# Proper way to realloc in c

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I have the following bit of code:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input_file","r");
size_t newsize = 1;
char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
char *text;
text = malloc(sizeof(char) * newsize);
strcpy(text,"");

while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
{
    newsize += strlen(buffer)
    text = realloc(text,newsize);
    strcat(text,buffer);
}
```

At the very end of my program, I `free(text)`. Do I need to free after every realloc? Right now my program "works" but when I run it through valgrind I get many errors.

Edit: I edited out all my other code, this is the error I get even before the realloc part

```
==3953== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7ff0004c0 --> 0x7fe85f190
==3953==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000304 or greater
==3953== Invalid write of size 4
==3953==    at 0x40076E: main (p21.c:37)
==3953==  Address 0x7fe85f19c is on thread 1's stack
==3953==
==3953== Invalid write of size 8
==3953==    at 0x400774: main (p21.c:37)
==3953==  Address 0x7fe85f190 is on thread 1's stack
==3953==
==3953== Invalid write of size 8
==3953==    at 0x400793: main (p21.c:43)
==3953==  Address 0x7fe85f188 is on thread 1's stack
==3953==
==3953== Invalid read of size 8
==3953==    at 0x4E8C38D: __fopen_maybe_mmap (iofopen.c:60)
==3953==    by 0x400797: main (p21.c:43)
==3953==  Address 0x7fe85f188 is on thread 1's stack
==3953==
==3953== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7fe85f190 --> 0x7ff0004c0
==3953==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=8000304 or greater
```

Comment: "_but when I run it through valgrind I get many errors_" - Please copy paste the errors here.

Comment: Posted the error @CoolGuy. It is giving me errors during the initialization part, but I am not sure why

Comment: I think I figured it out.. When I make char[buffer] too big it is giving me those errors. What is the max size I can store into buffer? I was using 4 million before and it didn't work. 1 million is working

Comment: That isn't a good way to go about allocating memory for the whole file.  It would be better to find the size of the file (`stat()`, `fstat()`, `ftell()`, etc) and allocate the space required and read the whole file at once.  As it is, you end up with quadratic behaviour as `strcat()` keeps on re-traversing the same data each time before it adds the new line's worth of data.

Comment: @PaperCode46 Don't throw a 1 MB or greater array into the stack like that. The stack is typically small in size ranging from 1 to 8 MBs. So, reduce the size of `MAX_SIZE` to something smaller, say 1000. But it doesn't make sense why you read data into a stack allocated array and then copy it into the heap instead of directly reading it into the heap. Allocate a small chunk of memory, read into it, allocate a bit more, read etc until no more data is left. Then `realloc` the required amount of memory

Comment: If you read a string of length N into a buffer, how much space do you need to allocate?  Does a string of length N fit into a buffer of size N?  Or does strcat over flow the buffer of size N?  To put it more directly, you aren't allocating enough space, as you have forgotten to include space for the terminal null.

Comment: @CoolGuy The text file I am reading in is about 30,000 lines which is over 2 million characters. Doesn't the buffer have to be that big?

Comment: @PaperCode46 No. That's why you have a loop. If `MAX_SIZE` is 1000, the loop would read a maximum of 999 characters (+1 for the `'\0'` at the end) in each iteration and append it to `text`. Think. If you used a 2 million sized buffer, what's the need for the loop? BTW, your approach is slow, as @JonathanLeffler said. Directly read into the heap as I said earlier.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to free after every realloc?

No. `realloc` frees the old memory block and gives you a new memory block to play with.

Unless it can expand the memory block without freeing it, in which case it does that and gives you the same block back. But also in this case, since nothing extra was allocated there's nothing extra to free.